# Python socket connection not working inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, sockets

I'm currently experimenting with Python sockets inside Docker containers.
For this I'm using this server side socket

```py
import socket

print("Starting...")
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(('localhost', 2222))
    print("Bound...")

    while True:
        print("Listening...")

        s.listen()

        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)

            recData = ""
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                print(f"Received: {data}")
                recData += data.decode("utf-8")
                conn.sendall(data)
            
            print(f"Received all: {recData}")
```

and this client side socket

```py
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect(("localhost", 2222))
    s.sendall(b"Hello, world")
    
    data = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")

    print(f"Received: {data}")
```

Also I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10-bullseye

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 2222/tcp 

CMD [ "python3", "-u", "main.py"]
```

When I now build and run this with
`docker build -t test .`
`docker run -d -p 2222:2222/tcp --name Test test`
and now run the client script on my PC while the server script is running this results in the output `Received:`
and the following on the server

```
Starting...
Bound...
Listening...
```

I'm very confused now why this is happening because everything should be mapped correctly.

Comment: If you run it in separated containers,  localhost will be different for each container. Use container names instead of localhost. At least, you should read the documentation about docker networks

Comment: @StanislavLu. At the moment only the server is running inside a container and the client on the PC itself

Comment: In the `s.bind()` call you _must_ bind to `0.0.0.0` and not `localhost`.  As @StanislavLu. notes, each container has its own `localhost`, and if the process binds only to its container-private `localhost` then it won't be reachable from other containers or from the host.